# How can I display a dynamic number of objects in a nice tile format in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to make application that can display 1 or 2 videos.

On the left part of the window there will be 2 buttons labeled "1" or "2" as number of tiles I want to display on the right side of the application.

By clicking "1" a video will be played on the entire right side.
By click "2" there will be displayed 2 videos on the right side, in 2 tiles.

For now its only full window tile that display 1 video, and another tile that split the full window to 2 and display 2 videos, but if I want 4 videos I would like to split the main window to 4 and display 4 different videos.

What is the best way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure you want to use `Canvas` for that grid-like kind of layout...?

Comment: I am reading about this right now, Maybe ListView with WrapPanel.

Comment: Or maybe you could use something like a `Grid` for your *grid*-like layout? ;-)

Comment: @bde - it's not a variable number of items.  It's 2 items, one of which may or may not contain a video.  If the app is only playing one video, then the other control may set its Visibility to Collapsed, and as long as the Grid's ColumnDefinition's Width is set to Auto, the other column will automatically resize to use all available space.

Comment: I want tile-look alike layout. for now its only full window tile that display 1 video, and another tile that split the full window to 2 and display 2 videos, but if i want 4 videos i would like to split the main window to 4 and display 4 different videos.

Comment: I want each button i click - will display a different tile, once the 1 video tile will be shown, and when i click the button a new tile will be displayed - showing 4 videos..

Comment: @WonkotheSane, you are right, comment retracted. For some reason I was thinking the tiles would be vertical and that a `Grid` with a `ListView` would be better, but a `Grid` should work either way.

Comment: So, what do you want?  The functionality defined in your question, or in your comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what you're saying in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140119/wpf-display-object-on-canvas-in-tile-look-alike#comment19581145_14140119), it sounds like you want buttons to create a dynamic number of videos and have them displayed nicely in a Grid

I would start by creating an `ObservableCollection<VideoPlayer>` in your [DataContext](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) that holds the number of videos you want, and a second property containing the Square Root of `VideoPlayerCollection.Count`, rounded up, for determining Grid size.

Then I'd display the `VideoPlayerCollection` using an `ItemsControl` that has it's `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `UniformGrid` or `Grid`, which binds the row count and column count to your `GridSize` property.

(You may need to build some `AttachedProperties` for binding these properties, as Grid's do not have a Row/Column count property, and I can't remember if the UniformGrid's `Rows` and `Columns` properties are `DependencyProperties` or not that you can bind to. I have an example of some AttachedProperties for binding a `Grid's` RowCount and ColumnCount [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) if you're interested in an example)

And finally, your Buttons would modify your `VideoPlayerCollection` to add or remove as many items as you want displayed.

So your final XAML might look something like this:

```
<DockPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Button Content="One Window" 
                Command="{Binding ModifyVideoCountCommand}"
                CommandParameter="1" />
        <Button Content="Two Windows" 
                Command="{Binding ModifyVideoCountCommand}"
                CommandParameter="2" />
        <Button Content="Four Windows" 
                Command="{Binding ModifyVideoCountCommand}"
                CommandParameter="4" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VideoPlayerCollection}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VideoPlayerTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding GridSize}" Columns="{Binding GridSize}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</DockPanel>
```

While the `DataContext` behind your form would contain these properties:

```
ICommand ModifyVideoCountCommand { get; set; }
ObservableCollection<VideoPlayer> VideoPlayerCollection { get; set; }
int GridSize 
{
    get
    {
        return Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(VideoPlayerCollection.Count));
    }
}
```

Depending on if you use a `Grid` or not, you may also need to add `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` properties to your `VideoPlayer` class to specify which `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` each VideoPlayer should be placed in.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" 
                Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" 
                Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```